# Rendering a string containing styling code

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've got an array containing questions and answers.  I have a component which will import the array and then output the contents.

However, I now need to add specific styling.  In my mind it should be possible to add inline styles as a string literal but this doesn't work:

**questionList.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";

export const questions = [
  {
    question: `This is regular text: ${(
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
        But this should be bold!
      </Text>
    )This is also regular text`,
    choices: [
      "Answer 1",
      "Answer 2",
      "Answer 3",
      "Answer 4",
    ]
  }
]
```

**RenderQuestion.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import { questions } from "../Data/questionList";

export const Question = () => (
  <View>
    <Text>{questions[0].question}</Text>
  </View>
);
```

What I get output looks like:
`This is regular text: [object Object] This is also regular text`

Is there a way to do this? *Should* I be doing this in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your questions data to have a component and not a string as a question.

Something like this should work:

```
export const questions = [
  {
    question: <Text>This is regular text: 
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
        But this should be bold!
      </Text>
      This is also regular text</Text>,
    choices: [
      "Answer 1",
      "Answer 2",
      "Answer 3",
      "Answer 4",
    ]
  }
];
```

Another alternative would be to use some markdown module if you want your data to be more readable and apply simple styles easier.

Something like this one for example [react-native-simple-markdown](https://github.com/CharlesMangwa/react-native-simple-markdown)